# How Can I Make This Scroll?

Tags: html, scroll, overflow

I'm currently making a character on ToyHouse, but can't seem to get this specific section in her profile to scroll. This is where I got the code from: https://toyhou.se/15434781.13-duotune-f2u/15434821.code
I've been testing on th.circlejourney.net

Anywhere I put `"overflow: auto;"`, nothing happens.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- 
        =====================================
            
               RELATIONSHIPS SECTION
            
        =====================================
        -->
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="RELATIONS">

  <!-- TAB HEADER -->
  <div class="row no-gutters p-2 pl-3 pr-3 text-uppercase" style="color: #ffbae1; pl-5 pr-5 pb-1" style="height: 350px; overflow: auto;">

    <!--
            =================================
            
                  RELATIONSHIP BLOCK
            
            =================================
            -->
    <div class="col-12 mt-lg-3; overflow: auto;">
      <div class="row no-gutters; overflow: auto;">

        <!-- RELATIONSHIP IMAGE -->
        <div class="card rounded-circle p-2 mt-4 mt-lg-0" style="height: 300px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;
                    
                    background-image: url(URLHERE);
                    background-size: cover;
                    background-position: center;">
          <div class="rounded-circle h-100" style="border: double 6px white; opacity: .6;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
        <p class="text-center text-uppercase" style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: 300;"><a style="color: #ffbae1;" target="_BLANK" href="CHARLINK_HERE">
                        
                        Character Name
                    
                    </a></p>

        <div class="row no-gutters mt-n1">
          <div class="col">
            <hr>
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto">
            <a class="tooltipster fad fa-heartbeat text-secondary fa-fw fa-2x mt-1 fa-beat" title="Relationship"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <hr>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="mb-3 p-4 p-lg-5 py-5 align-items-center" style="min-height: 250px; position: relative; font-style: italic; font-size: 18px; text-align: center;">
          <i class="fal fa-quote-left fa-2x" style="color: #ffbae1; position: absolute; left: 5px; top: 5px;"></i>
          <p>

            Describe a relationship with a quote. Duis sollicitudin elit sed tellus blandit viverra sed eget odio.

          </p>
          <i class="fal fa-quote-right fa-2x" style="color: #ffbae1; position: absolute; right: 5px; bottom: 0px;"></i>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I added bootstrap 5. Please update the snippet and the tags to reflect the version of bootstrap you are using. Right now nothing shows in the viewport